# Understanding Uniswap V2: removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens event log

Tags: ether, etherscan

I am new to Ethereum world and I'm trying to understand how liquidity pools work. While I understand the basic concept, I am having a hard time following [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf083a1841761ff17221f870ff0f84a46a35388dbe05bc2c93a6c284f257d846a):
This is transaction log for `removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` method. My understanding so far:

1. User sends `1403597151776567996020`liquidity tokens to the router to remove it form the pool.
2. Uniswap redirect the transaction and send the liquidity tokens to `Uniswap: STA` contract.
3. The liquidity tokens ( `1403597151776567996020`) are destroyed by sending them to null address.
4. Corresponding amount of WrappedETH and STA tokens are sent to the router (Log index 52 and 53).
5. Some amount is destroyed by sending it to null address (Log index 54). The amount shown is `10335205196850821727352`. I'm not sure what this is. I am assuming this could be transfer fee?
6. The new amounts available in the pool are syncéd/published? Not sure what this means.
7. Next, corresponding amounts are removed from the pool i.e. `amount0 : 2139761524955797868` and `amount1 :1033520519685082172735111`. Why is this amount different to the one that was transferred to the router in step 4 above (Log index 52 and 53)?
8. Next the amounts removed from the pool are transferred back somewhere (Log index 57 - 59). I'm not sure how those amounts are calculated and why does log number 58 denote something being sent to null address again?

Can someone please explain as to what exactly is going on? Your help will be greatly appreciated.